# Join query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables:

1. Car_company which has the attributes of:
   *C_id* (primary key),
   *C_name*
2. Car_model which has the attributes of:
   *Com_id* (referenced to *C_id* of Car_company),
   *Model_year*
   *Warranty*

I wish to access both of these tables individually and also I would like to perform a join operation on them and display all of the car_models along with their car_company name. I tried using both JPQL and native query but nothing worked. I also made sure to use the OneToMany and ManyToOne associations but I ended up getting infinite nesting,i.e, the models have car_company as field, this inturn has car_models as a list, and this keeps going. Please help me with entity classes and DAOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a List of CarModel for each car company in the CarCompany entity through the oneToMany annotation like this:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carCompany", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CarModel> carModels;
```

or get all car models with their company field in the CarModel entity like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Com_id", referencedColumnName = "C_id", nullable = false)
private CarCompany carCompany;
```

Just try to define your relationships as LAZY for performance purpose and to prevent circular nesting when you map your responses to a Data Transfer Object (DTO).